# Enum raises AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute '_member_names'

Tags: python, enums

I am trying to create an Enum class dynamically, using type(name, base, dict).

```
from enum import Enum

class FriendlyEnum(Enum):
    def hello(self):
        print(self.name + ' says hello!')
```

The normal way works fine:

```
class MyEnum(FriendlyEnum):
    foo = 1
    bar = 2

MyEnum.foo.hello()

# ->
foo says hello!
```

But if I try dynamically:

```
MyEnum = type('MyEnum',
    (FriendlyEnum,),
    {'foo':1,'bar':2}
)

MyEnum.foo.hello()

# ->
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/enum.py", line 146, in __new__
enum_members = {k: classdict[k] for k in classdict._member_names}
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute '_member_names'
```

Any suggestions?

It might be useful for testing the methods of a parent Enum class, dynamically creating new Enum classes with different attributes and same inherited methods.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `Enum` class [can be called](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#functional-api) to dynamically create a new `Enum` type. This will also work for subclasses of `Enum`

```
MyEnum = FriendlyEnum('MyEnum', {'foo': 1, 'bar': 2})
MyEnum.foo.hello()
```

Answer (score 1):

An explanation of why it's not working: `EnumMeta` is expecting the class dictionary (`classdict` above) to be an instance of `enum._EnumDict`, but what you gave it was a normal dict (hence no `_member_names` attribute).

Using `type` to directly create an `enum` is not supported -- use the method [outlined by Iain Shelvington](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69328391/208880) instead.